# Validate input length

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm using `Angular` and `Angular Material`. When validating input length using the `minlength` validator, empty input slips through. Is there a built-in support to validate "empty or shorter than"?

I could use `required` in combination with `minlength`, however, `Angular Material` styles such input and that's not desirable.

Should I implement custom validator?

Comment: please share your code, so someone can help.

Comment: So you are trying not to use validator `required`?

Comment: @Nehal precisely, as the field gets styled (thanks to the Angular Material) and that's something I'm trying to avoid

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "field gets styled"!! Can you explain little bit more?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion nethan. Basically the design library appends asterisk to the field name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could use required in combination with minlength, however, Angular
>   Material styles such input and that's not desirable.

You could simply override their styling and it wouldn't be an issue.

Or you could, like you said, create a custom validator. But this should be used with `FormBuilder` which I'm not sure that you are using.

Here's one you could use, when given a better name of course:

```
export const MyCustomValidator = (length: number): ValidatorFn => {

  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {

    return ((!value ||) (value < length)) ? null : {
      myCustom: true
    };
  };
};
```

Comment: Yea, I'm not using `FormBuilder`, however, your mention of styles made me take another look and apparently Angular Material added `hideRequiredMarker` recently and that solves the problem